# How to get current Ember app route from template

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to set element class attributes based on current route. This is inside a navigation handlebars partial included in the Application handlebars template.

In my ApplicationController I can do something like:

```
isUsers: ( ->
  @get('currentPath') == 'users.index'
).property('currentPath')
```

In the navigation template I want to do something like:

```
<a {{bind-attr class="isUsers:active:inactive"}} href="users"></a>
```

This doesn't work - inactive class is always set, even when in correct app path.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are defining the `isUsers` property in the ApplicationController, then are you sure you are using it in the `application.handlebars` or whatever template used by the ApplicationController? If you are using in a template which has a different Controller, make sure you use the following in your controller.

```
App.MyController = App.Controller.extend
  needs: ['application']
```

In the template,

```
controllers.application.isUsers
```